# Xcode 8.3 - Delete Bundle Identifier Locally?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a free developer account tier that I'm using for some test projects.

I created the project with the bundle identifier `com.somedomain.myproject` and after I created it, I realized I had objective-c language instead of swift.

I deleted the project and created a new one with the same bundle identifier `com.somedomain.myproject`. I receive this message now saying:

`Failed to create provisioning profile.
The app ID "com.somedomain.myproject" cannot be registered to your development team. Change your bundle identifier to a unique string to try again.`

So, does that bundle id save somewhere locally on my machine even after I have deleted the previous project? I could not see anything on `developer.apple.com` (since I have a free account) and could not find anywhere else to delete it.

I want to be able to use that same bundle id I originally had in the first creation.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the bundle identifier you chose belongs to another developer. There is nothing you can do about that error other than to follow its advice and use a new bundle identifier.